# Problema al leer y mostrar el género desde registros binarios de estudiantes en C

Tags: c, subida-de-archivos

Estoy trabajando en un programa en C que debe leer un archivo binario que contiene datos de estudiantes, incluyendo el género. Estoy utilizando una estructura llamada StudentRecord que incluye una bandera (flags) para el género. La bandera está configurada de manera que el bit menos significativo (& 1) indica el género, donde 1 representa "Femenino" y 0 representa "Masculino". Sin embargo, cuando ejecuto el programa, todos los estudiantes se muestran como "Masculino", incluso si la bandera debería indicar "Femenino".

He revisado el código y la estructura de datos varias veces, pero no puedo encontrar el problema. ¿Puede alguien ayudarme a entender por qué se muestra incorrectamente el género y cómo puedo solucionar este problema?

Adjunto aquí el código relevante:

```
// Código relevante para leer y mostrar el género de estudiantes
// ...
if (student.age >= age_min && student.age <= age_max) {
   // Problema aquí: El género siempre se muestra como "Masculino"
   printf("%-30s%-30u%-10s\n", student.name, student.age, (student.flags & 1) == 1 ? "Femenino" : "Masculino");
}
// ...
```

Aprecio cualquier ayuda o sugerencia para resolver este problema. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Asegúrate de que obtienes, guardas y cargas bien los datos. No podemos ayudarte si no muestras un [mre].

Comment: Muchas gracias @Mateo. El archivo binario que estoy cargando no fue generado por mí, y la fuente de los datos asegura que el archivo está en un formato correcto y válido:
ID del Estudiante: 32 bits
Banderas: 8 bits (La bandera F es 1 si el estudiante es femenino y 0 si el estudiante es masculino. La bandera G es 1 si el usuario es estudiante de posgrado y 0 en caso contrario.)
El código completo está en mi github: https://github.com/vhenaoi/Curso_Platzi/blob/main/Taller1/imprimirArchivo.c

Comment: El problema que veo es que estás comparando la bandera con 1 en lugar de simplemente verificar si es igual a 0 o no. En otras palabras, en lugar de: (student.flags & 1) == 1 ? "Femenino" : "Masculino", deberías usar: (student.flags & 1) ? "Femenino" : "Masculino"

Comment: Claramente el problema no está ahí. Por lo que veo y el compilador te alerta, estás excediendo el tamaño del arreglo y terminas pisando el valor de `flags`. Además, inspeccionando el archivo se puede ver que los nombres de mujer tienen el byte `0x80` y no `1`. Deberías haber colocado el código del archivo que compartiste en la pregunta.